# TypeORM RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for %% was found. how register the repository using schemas

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

Im using TypeORM I define my entity using "entity schemas", in one file i define de my entity

> ./enteties/catalago.entity.ts

```
export const CarreraEntity = new EntitySchema<Carrera>({
name: 'carrera',
columns: {
    id: {
        type: Number,
        generated: 'increment',
        primary: true
    },
    text: {
        type: String
    }
}});
```

in other file i define my schemas

> ./enteties/catalog.schemas.ts

```
export abstract class Catalogs {
id: number;
text: string;}
export class Carrera extends Catalogs {}
```

but when i run, get the error

> RepositoryNotFoundError: No repository for "Carrera" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

id the [docs](https://typeorm.io/#/separating-entity-definition) is not clear where register the entity